# SQL query doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:
MENU
m_id
m_name (menu name)
m_content (content of the page)
m_p_id (plugin id)
m_s_id (status id)

PLUGINS
p_id
p_name (plugin name, for example Gallery)
p_file (gallery.php)

STATUS
s_id
s_name (active or passive)

I would like to see these in an HTML table:
m_id
m_name
m_content
p_name
s_name

This is my query:

```
SELECT m_id, m_name, m_content, s_name,p_name
        FROM menu, status, plugins
        WHERE m_s_id=s_id AND m_p_id=p_id
```

The problem is, that I can't see the rows, where the m_p_id is empty(NULL in the column).

Comment: Why do you think that query doesn't work as expected? Why it must shows the rows where `m_p_id` is `null`?

Comment: How to say it in SQL, that i want to see those rows too?

Comment: If your m_p_id column is empty, you can't see your data. You need to do a JOIN, hence m_p_id should be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
SELECT m_id, m_name, m_content, s_name, p_name
FROM menu
LEFT JOIN status ON m_s_id=s_id
LEFT JOIN  plugins ON m_p_id=p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't

Because you need to [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) those tables